# Numerical date to string conversion

Tags: php, date

I am using the following code to convert a date in the format `mm/dd/yy` to show `November, 19, 2008`

```
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime('{$month}/{$day}/{$year}'));
```

In my database I have the values for `$month`, `$day` and `$year` stored as an `INT`.

When I add the variables into the date function, the output is wrong. I am getting an unexpected date. The date I have in the system is `2/1/1977` but the output gives `December 31, 1969`.

any ideas?

Comment: What is the output, and what where you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem isyour single quotes around the string in `strtotime`

Single quotes wont parse and put in the variables value, it will be exactly that literal.  you want to use doubles

```
$month = 1; $day = 2; $year = 2000;
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime("$month/$day/$year")); 
echo '    {$month}/{$day}/{$year}';  //gives exactly whats between the single quotes
```

Output :

```
January 02, 2000    {$month}/{$day}/{$year}
```

---

### EDIT

```
for($=0;$i<count($month);$i++)
   echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($month[$i].'/'.$day[$i].'/'.$year[$i])) . '<br />';
```

Comment: How can i repeat this function for each row of users?

Comment: these users and their birthdays are in an array?

Comment: No, the are stored seperately.  I have 3 data fields: month, day, year.  so each of them hold a number..

Comment: so month day and year are parallel arrays?

Comment: OK.  Now i am trying to use ob_start(); to capture the data into a variable.  I am doing it the following way but it just shows me a blank screen:        ob_start();
for($=0;$i<count($month);$i++)
   echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($month[$i].'/'.$day[$i].'/'.$year[$i])) . '<br />';
$test = ob_get_contents();

Comment: did you try echoing `$test`?  also, do you really want all of this in one big string or do you want an array of formatted dates?

Comment: Yes.  it still gave me a blank screen, i think because i am using the ob_start(); in the middle of the query.... formatted dates would be better i guess. thanks jon_darkstar!