# Conversion of Date string to word issue PHP string

Tags: php, string, date

I am converting a string number to `strtotime` and then attempting to get a written date outputted. This is working to an extent but the issue is that the dates are wrong.

**THE PHP**

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

function dateRange($start, $end) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $diff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);

    $daysBetween = floor($diff/(60*60*24));

    $formattedDates = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $daysBetween; $i++) {
       // $tmpDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . " + $i days"));
        $tmpDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . " + $i days"));
      //  $formattedDates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tmpDate));
        $formattedDates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tmpDate));
    }    
    return $formattedDates;
}


$start=$date_system_installed;
$end=$today;

$formattedDates = dateRange($start, $end);

foreach ($formattedDates as $dt)
{
    $date = strtotime($dt);
    echo date('l jS F Y',$date);
}
```

**The outputted dates**

[image: Dates table]

**The true dates that should be showing but in text**

[image: True Dates]

Where am i going wrong for this to output the correct format but incorrect dates?

Comment: I found [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5463903/) under Related >>> (it might help).

Comment: Why don't you use DateInterval and DatePeriod? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d for an example.

Comment: I just posted an example using `DateInterval` as an answer below. It was quicker than debugging the existing code :) hope that's ok

Comment: I'm down voting you because you say the dates are wrong, but not how they are wrong, and your examples don't match up at all.  Give us the inputs you are using to generate the bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a date range function I wrote that generates an array of formatted dates. It uses the `DateTime()` functions which will give you more accurate intervals than things like `60*60/24`.

```
/**
 * Creates an array of dates between `$start` and `$end`, intervaled by a day
 *
 * @param string $start Start date string
 * @param string $end End date string
 * @param string $format Date format
 * @param boolean $inclusive Whether or not to include the start and end dates
 * @return array Array of dates between the two
 */
    function dateRange($start = null, $end = null, $format = 'Y-m-d', $inclusive = true) {
        if (empty($start) || empty($end)) {
            return array();
        }
        $start = new DateTime($start);
        $end = new DateTime($end);
        if ($inclusive) {
            $end = $end->modify('+1 day');
        } else {
            $start = $start->modify('+1 day');
        }

        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
        $daterange = array();
        foreach ($period as $date) {
            $daterange[] = $date->format($format);
        }
        return $daterange;
    }
```

And a test case

```
function testDateRange() {
        $results = dateRange('2012-02-20', '2012-03-01');
        $expected = array(
            '2012-02-20',
            '2012-02-21',
            '2012-02-22',
            '2012-02-23',
            '2012-02-24',
            '2012-02-25',
            '2012-02-26',
            '2012-02-27',
            '2012-02-28',
            '2012-02-29',
            '2012-03-01'
        );
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $results);

        $results = dateRange('2012-02-24', '2012-03-01', 'M j');
        $expected = array(
            'Feb 24',
            'Feb 25',
            'Feb 26',
            'Feb 27',
            'Feb 28',
            'Feb 29',
            'Mar 1'
        );
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $results);

        $results = dateRange('2012-02-25', '2012-03-01', 'Y-m-d', false);
        $expected = array(
            '2012-02-26',
            '2012-02-27',
            '2012-02-28',
            '2012-02-29'
        );
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $results);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code - it's all ok
http://codepad.org/E18ccpxV